# How to pack several DataFrames into one file using zipfile

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-zipfile

I have a few DataFrames that I need to zip to one file.
This is my code:

```
df_list = [ojcowskieDF,mateczneDF]
with zipfile.ZipFile('final.zip', 'w') as zipF:
    for file in df_list:
        zipF.write(file, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

But I get this error:`TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not DataFrame`
Does anyone know how to zip a few DF? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need first to convert your dataframes to .csv by using [**`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv) or to .xlsx by using [**`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).

```
import zipfile
import os

list_df = [ojcowskieDF, mateczneDF]

with zipfile.ZipFile('final.zip', 'w') as zf:
    i=1 #this iterator to make sure each .csv will have a different name
    for df in list_df:
        df.to_csv(f'sample_{i}.csv') #this will convert the dataframe to a .csv
        zf.write(f'sample_{i}.csv') #this will put the .csv in the zipfile
        os.remove(f'sample_{i}.csv') #this will delete the .csv created 
        i+=1
```